# Eating after Zeman Tefila if one didn't pray

Tags: halacha, eating

If someone wakes up at let's say 11:00 and Sof Zeman Tefila according to all Posekim passed, can that person eat? We know that one can't eat before Tefila (Shulhan Aruch וידוע) but maybe the Din here is different when the Zeman passes.

Comment: Is the person planning on davening shacharit still?

Comment: @DoubleAA yessir.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46059/759