# Can someone eat before davening if you overslept and missed Shacharis?

Tags: halacha, tefilla

Can someone eat (or do other prohibited things) before praying the Shemoneh Esrei of mincha if they overslept and missed shacharis (and hence had not prayed until then)?

Comment: Samuch lamincha ein yoshvin leechol without this

Comment: This has been asked before

Comment: [Asked,](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46059/eating-before-davening-mincha-when-one-hasnt-davened-shachris?rq=1) but not answered.

Comment: As @kouty mentioned, you aren't allowed to eat before Mincha regardless (at least under normal circumstances). Why should having missed Shacharis be more lenient?

Comment: @Salmononius2 Assuming that person holds that only applies to Mincha Ketana and a large seudah etc etc